# How do you create an Excel table with row headers instead of column headers?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm dealing with an Excel table that has hundreds of columns but only a dozen rows.

Many of the columns use mathematical formulas that reference the data in other columns to produce their results.

There's a lot of dependency between columns, so it's nice to be able to reference the column names in formulas in order to keep track of how each calculation is being computed.

The problem is, this table is **unreadable**.

The table is far too wide, and too short - you have to scroll horizontally forever to see different columns, which makes it difficult to observe chaining modifications - entering a different value in column `A` changes the result values of any cell that references column `A` in its formula.

I'm using this table to map out mathematically precise dependent calculations that keep track of the dimensions of various mechanical parts that I'm using in an engineering project, so being able to make changes and keep track of the chaining modifications is critical.

My question is, is there any way to rotate my entire table 90 degrees counter-clockwise, while keeping this basic table functionality?
It'd be much easier to read long and skinny, rather than short and fat.

This would require the column headers to become row headers, and inside my formulas my **column name references** would turn in to **row name references**.

I'm OK with creating a fresh new table from scratch and re-entering data and formulas, if that's easiest.
I just need to know how to get Excel to make row headers for me instead of column headers.

Comment: Wait, counter-clockwise? Are the headers on the left side? Or is it something like [this](http://puu.sh/nALzO/5c8ef73770.png) (image)?

Comment: @dma1324 My table currently has lots of columns, but just a few rows, with headers at the top (like a normal table). I want to rotate it counter-clockwise, so the headers are on the left, and the few long rows turn into a few long columns.

Comment: Have you tried paste special -> transpose?

Comment: @Kyle Yeah, but that just gives me a static copy - which won't populate changes back to the original table. Producing a copy of my table doesn't help my situation, it only further complicates the usage of this workbook.

Comment: @Giffyguy It's not static, your formulas are updated accordingly with paste special -> transpose (you may need to convert to range first). Regardless, the answer to your question is no. Excel tables cannot have row headers. You can try using named ranges to emulate the effect.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Transpose array formula, select the new place of your Table by converting number of columns and rows (hundreds of rows and dozen of column in your case) insert Transpose Formula, in the arguments array select your old table and click Ctrl+Shift+Enter for the array formula
NB: your Formulas should be updated accordingly.
----------- you need to correct it-----------------------------
You can Copy again the new table and use paste special value for normal data and formulas will need correction

Comment: This would create a copy of the data, which I won't be able to edit directly.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is, is there any way to rotate my entire table 90 degrees counter-clockwise, while keeping this basic table functionality?

No, unfortunately there is currently no way for creating an Excel table with header column instead of header row.

Also I'm not aware of any other spreadsheet tool which would support that.

Answer (score 1):

Years passed but in 2023 the Excel still does not support such feature.
I don't have a proper solution as well, but I would like to share some of approaches which I used when I needed something like that that:

- **Named Cells**. If you wish to have only one column of data and many rows of attributes, you can do it without table definition, but define a custom name for every cell. That way you can reference other attributes by name. The drawback here is that you don't see attribute names like headers in the table, so you have to manually create a column with attribute names and keep it in sync with named regions (named cells). Renames are also not as simple as in a table. However, there is a very useful operation in Excel for this: *Formulas -> Defined Names -> Create from Selection*. It can automatically create named cells for a long list of name/value pairs. (You might get into troubles if you are going to reorder and update names too much. But in general, this is my preferable option.)
- **Compact Layout**. Keep your table horizontal as it is the only option in Excel, but adjust a text layout so that more attributes become visible in a screen. For example, rotate all text in headers and data cells so that if flows from top to bottom. The result looks crazy, but you get much more records visible in one screen. This option definitely does not fit for long time work with data.
- **Read-only View**. Create a read-only vertical presentation of the table which is always in sync with the original horizontal table. This can be done with the recently added function [TRANSPOSE](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/transpose-function-ed039415-ed8a-4a81-93e9-4b6dfac76027). So, if you have a table named Table1, then you can make it like this `=TRANSPOSE(Table1[#All])` and you will see exactly what you want - properly transposed table with headers on the left side as row names, and values on the right. The drawback here is that you cannot edit this table, only view. For editing you have to go back to horizontal table. Also there could be troubles with number formatting which is not considered by the TRANSPOSE function. So, this option fits for cases when you rarely edit values and frequently read them.
- **Key-Value Table**. Finally, if you are frequently and intensively modifying a large number of attributes, it can be represented as a table of two columns: Key and Value. For all references within the data you would need to use a formula like this `=VLOOKUP("myAttribute",Table1,2,FALSE)`. For the sake of making it shorter and simpler, a [LAMBDA](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/lambda-function-bd212d27-1cd1-4321-a34a-ccbf254b8b67) function can be defined, so if you call it Get(key), then you can end up with formulas like `= ( GET("Order_Price") + GET("Delivery_Price") ) * GET("VAT")`. The drawback here is that you would need to enter attribute names manually, you don't have suggestions, and any attribute rename becomes a true nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Quantrix Modeler. It's designed around the concept of multi-dimensional matrices of data; changing orientations of rows/headers, having nested dimensions etc is effortless, and makes formulas much more readable. However, there is a veeeery steep learning curve, it is expensive, and its charting capabilities are really limited and ugly compared to Excel. But it may be what you're looking for.